# Referencing to the value of an object inside angular {{ }} html markup

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-material

I'm in AngularJS 1 and I would like to show the value of the element I'm displaying, by referencing to the value of an object that has for key the value of the element.

Currently my implementation is very inefficient, as I have two versions of the same values, on as an Array of Objects, the other as an Object (which I use to create the `select` element).

Example:

```
timezonesArrOfObj = {
    { value : "Europe/Dublin", string : "(GMT) Dublin"},
    { value : "Europe/Lisbon", string : "(GMT) Lisbon"},
    { value : "Europe/London", string : "(GMT) London"}
}

timezonesObj = {
    "Europe/Dublin" : "(GMT) Dublin",
    "Europe/Lisbon" : "(GMT) Lisbon",
    "Europe/London" : "(GMT) London"
}
```

Currently, when I want to display the value, I do this:

```
{{ timezonesObj[element.Timezone] }}
```

However, it would be more efficient to reuse the `timezonesArrOfObj`, but how could I associate the proper key with the value of `element.Timezone` to show the right `timezonesArrOfObj[ (index of key == element.Timezone) ].string`?

Btw, I need the `timezonesArrOfObj` as I want to be sure of the order in which timezones are listed in the `select` element.

// EDIT

Merging the comment from xSaber and the response from Vaibhav, I've ended up doing this:

```
.filter('getObjString', function() {
    return function(args){
        return args.obj[_.findIndex(args.obj, { value : args.val })].string 
    };
});
```

and html:

```
{{ { val : element.timezone, obj : timezonesArrOfObj } | getObjString }}
```

Comment: If you're using lodash/underscore library in your project, you could :
`{{ timezoneArrOfObj[_.findIndex(timezoneArrOfObj, { value : element.Timezone })].string }}`
Pretty hard, yes, probably it would be better to decouple this into controller's method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great if you can use a `filter` instead.

Something like below :

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  var timezonesArrOfObj = [
        { value : "Europe/Dublin", string : "(GMT) Dublin"},
        { value : "Europe/Lisbon", string : "(GMT) Lisbon"},
        { value : "Europe/London", string : "(GMT) London"}
    ];
  return function(input, arg){
    angular.forEach(timezonesArrOfObj, function(key, value){
      if(arg == key.value){
        console.log('yes they are equal');
        return key;
      }
    });
  };
});
```

in HTML :

all you need is to use this filter wherever you are binding your result :

```
{{element.timezone | myFilter}}
```

I hope this helps. Do let me know in case of any issue.